# Block internet access for iPad apps

Tags: ios

I would like to block internet access for a certain app on my iPad. The device is used for note taking hence I would like to keep my data private. At the moment my solution is to keep the device offline. For obvious reasons, I would like to have internet access but restrict certain apps to “call home”.

Additionally, when updating an app is it possible for the vendor to get hold of the data in the app or does the update run on an OS level so that without opening the app there is no way to get the data?

I’ve disabled cloud backups and text recognition.

Comment: Why would you input sensitive data into an app which you don't trust not to do nefarious stuff during an update?

Comment: Might be useful if we knew which app...

Comment: @foreverska because the app provides useful writing features and is capable of clearly organizing my notes. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin doesn’t matter the app name. It’s not the Apple Notes app, though.